# Southeast Asia LUIS returning 500 errors

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Since this morning I haven't been able to connect to my LUIS instance in Southeast Asia.

```
    using (var luis = new LuisClient("AppIdHere", "SecretKeyHere", domain: "southeastasia"))
    {
        try
        {
            return await luis.Predict(message.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

The message returned is: "応答の状態コードは成功を示していません: 500 (Internal Server Error)。"

Extra Info:

Using Microsoft.Cognitive.LUIS version 2.0.2 in a BotFramework project targeting dotnet framework 4.6.

Comment: Contact support: http 500 is problems on the server side.

Comment: Pinged them on Twitter and they requested I ask the question here :D

Comment: Show your tweet. You really cannot do anything with http 500 on a remote server.